# fix invalid geometries in django (without database)

Tags: python, django, postgis, geos

I have polygon that I'm getting from external source. The polygon is not valid.

```
In [36]: p
Out[36]: <Polygon object at 0x7fec6bea6ac0>

In [37]: p.valid
[12/Dec/2017 19:13:19] WARNING [django.contrib.gis:85] GEOS_NOTICE: Hole lies outside shell at or near point 260561.40600000042 776052
```

I know that I can fix the polygon in the DB using the MakeValid() django function.

Is there a way to fix the polygon before it is inserted to the DB, just using geos API?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're misconstruing using a db function with a data update.  Using `MakeValid` doesn't update the actual record itself until you explicitly call save.

Comment: thanks. I know. The problem I has is that the polygon itself is currently not in the DB.

Comment: I  feel you should be able to use that function without requiring a db value, as long as the polygon is in WKT or other postgis format.  eg `SELECT ST_MAKEVALID(POLYGON('WKT text here'));`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that this will fix your hole error necessarily, but I have had luck eliminating self-intersecting geoms by performing a 0-width buffer:

```
p = p.buffer(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ST_MakeValid` function is unfortunately not using a geos function, but is [a custom function](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/1eb5e0a8d9ed56b4e82577d5168d0e9fba92d6bd/liblwgeom/lwgeom_geos_clean.c#L340) in PostGIS' own liblwgeom library.

I am not aware of any python bindings for liblwgeom, so if you want to call that function, you would have to do your own binding with ctypes. See [this similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278431) for inspiration.

But if any method is good enough, I was also successful just using `buffer(0)`, as suggested by in [spatialbits' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814595/758345).